# I found 2 patent,which are over 26 years ,but still in force,can someone help tell me why?

Tags: expire, day

I am studying the Patent Numbers 5,161,396 and 5,549,337 and found
Grant date of 
5161396 is on NOV 10, 1992 ,
5549337 is on AUG 27, 1996
they are over patent protechtion time,but they are all in force
can someone help me and tell me why?
thank you

Comment: Why do you think they are still in force?

Comment: I suppose it is possible that a company could take a license to a patent those terms run beyond the expiration date, but both of those patents are expired.

Comment: @EricShain that actually happens when company license a portfolio because of a strong patent and that then expires or when a patent is revoked after licensing. Normally they are then stuck with the license. Somebody licensing an expired patent ... well ... would be a mistake ;)

Comment: i studied these two patens  on http://www.patentbuddy.com/Patent/5161396 and found the status is in force,that's why it's so strange

Comment: @EricShain Once a patent expires, there would be no further need for a license as the invention is no longer "the property" of the patent owners and anyone can make, use, sell or import it without license.  Tying it to other patents or products might be a "patent misuse" to stifle competition unlawfully.

Comment: @Upnorth I know that. I was just speculating on why someone would state that an expired patent was still in force.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, both the cited patents are clearly expired. There are no provisions I am aware of for having them extended. This doesn't mean the company who owns the patents wouldn't list the patents, or has newer patents that are still in force.